# Recursive CTE query with inner join

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I am hoping someone can help with a query I want to build. I have a table that stores hierarchy data in parent child format with one top node. Multiple levels, and each parent having multiple children. And I have another node with the description of the child nodes I want to retrieve. How can I write a recursive query to select only the parent child rows from a particular node down to the last child including the descriptions?

Example

Table 1 - Hierarchy Nodes

```
Parent|child 
1     |2 
1     |3 
2     |4 
2     |5 
3     |6 
3     |7 
6     |8
```

Table 2 - Node Descriptions

```
Node  |Description 
1     |Tom
2     |Ben
3     |Jerry 
4     |Alice
5     |James 
6     |John 
7     |Peter
8     |Paul
```

How can I retrieve only rows from node 3 and all its descendants and descriptions like the results below?

```
Parent|child |Description
3     |6     |John
3     |7     |Peter
6     |8     |Paul
```

Thanks much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com is not a free coding service. What query have you attempted? Please add it to the question. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help especially under the heading **Asking**

Comment: Here is what I have I tried:

Comment: How does this question differ to an apparently identical one asked just 3 hours earlier? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47560559/recursive-query-for-parent-child-hierarchy-get-descendants-from-a-top-node

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: please don't waste our time asking duplicate questions, the earlier question has already been answered with the ONLY difference (I can see) is that you have added a column for name.  The query does not change because on that column, just add the column into the appropriate select clauses.

Comment: The difference is that there is a primary join condition. Here is what I have tried:

Comment: WITH Hierarchy AS
      (
          SELECT  Table1.Parent,
   Table1.Child,
   Table2.Description
          FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Child = Table2.Description
          WHERE where Parent = 3
          UNION ALL
          SELECT rel.Table1.Parent,
   rel.Table1.Child,
   rel.Table2.Description
          FROM Hierarchy hier
               INNER JOIN Table1 rel ON hier.Child = rel.Parent
      )
  SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy